# What's the NGINX equivalent of console.log or print?

Tags: nginx

I want to see which server and location context that Nginx executed.

I've created a `log_format` directive in the http block (it errored when I set it in the server or location context) and set different access_logs based on the location.

But is this necessary? Is there a way to add info to the access_log, e.g. "Location two of the sample domain executed"?

Comment: I think you're getting it wrong. Nginx isn't a programming language, so you can't have an equivalent function to log stuff as you wish as in a programming language. What you can do, is to create a pair of access.log plus error.log files per server.

Comment: @Marcel Yeah I thought the answer'd be something like that. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could maybe get some debugging information with a custom header with the `add_header` directive:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    add_header X-my-debug "Location two of the sample domain executed";
}
```

You could then read the header using `curl`:

```
# curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2020 15:49:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 11321
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 19:34:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "593af836-2c39"
X-my-debug: Location two of the sample domain executed
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

You could also use your browser console / developer tools to have a look at the response headers in the network tab.

Comment: [Note](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) `[add_header] directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.` - adding such directive may have unintended side-effects.

Comment: I missed this  I am so sorry for not accepting this sooner. Thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: Everything cool  I hope this helped you!